# HTML5- Safari doesn't play or recognize the <video>

Tags: html, video, safari, version, compatibility

ok, I am creating a website with a video as a background. Here is the code:

```
<video id="video1" autoplay loop preload poster="" muted>
    <source src="video/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="video/video2.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

and here is the css:

```
video#video1 
{ 
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: -100;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer and Firefox work well, the only one giving me problems is Safari. Any ideas?

the safari version is 5.1.7(7534.572)

Comment: is this Safari on Windows (current OSX version is 9.1, so I assume so) then it's a deprecated product and IIRC didn't include support for H.264 container. I'd recommend simply not supporting Safari on Windows

Comment: I have windows indeed. so... if I leave the code as it is... and someone opens the website in a safari browser from a... mac... would it work?

Comment: I have a Mac, share the link and I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have QuickTime installed for Windows Safari to have .mp4 support.

Comment: Done!! It works now. Thank you so much. Now I have to find a way to mute it XD I have muted on the <video> tag but it's ignoring it. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

as you can see and in here safari doesnt support video type webm...only mp4